# Heat equation on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Do we use the same technique (separation of variables) to derive the solution of heat equation as in this link (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeatConductionEquation.html) in the complex plane?

If so, the the solution would be given by equation $(10)$ with x replaced by complex variable $z$, right?

Comment: Does this arise from any application? Usually, one has two dimensional heat equation with real variables (eg. $x,y$) which could be solved by the complex techniques, where we take $z=x+iy$. But I haven't encountered the case you seem to mean

Comment: No, it doesn't arise from any practical application. I don't have any boundary or initial conditions. I also know real two and three dimensional case. My question is if we take $u=u(t,z)$ with $t$ real, can we have the same solution?

Comment: Usually what happens is, you find a known solution on a standard domain (i.e. the upper-half plane), then use conformal mappings to transform the solution into the domain that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, yes.

Also note that the theta function provides a solution to the fundamental heat equation. Use $u(x,t) = \theta(x,it)$ to solve $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$ Quite straightforwardly, $$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}-\pi i n^2 e^{2\pi inx-\pi i n^2t} = \frac{1}{4\pi}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}-4\pi^2n^2e^{2\pi i nx-\pi i n^2t} $$

See [Is Jacobi Theta function same as Heat Kernel ? How to derive Jacobi Theta from Heat Kernel?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372436/is-jacobi-theta-function-same-as-heat-kernel-how-to-derive-jacobi-theta-from-h)